# How to display weather radar map on website?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, plugins, content-management-system

I'm specifically looking for a weather radar map, similar to this one to display on a Wordpress website: http://www.vantilburgfarms.com/weather_local_radar.htm

The radar above is animated and zoomed in on the Indiana, Ohio part of the US, which is exactly what I need. **I don't want to steal this map from the website.**

I've Googled this and the only things I can find are 5-day forecasts. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try looking at the source of your example page? That'd tell you a LOT about what you need to do.

Comment: Marc - the website will not allow you to view the page source. Whenever you right click the page, a message box displays, "Function disabled by VTF, INC!"

Comment: @candyA - Then use Ctrl+Shift-I in Chrome (or whatever the similar hotkey is for the browser of your choice) to open the browser's developer tools to look at the rendered source.

Comment: ctrl-U in firefox, or the view menu will all do it... right-click is just one way to get at it. Right-click disablers are pathetically easy to get around.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I normally use Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at their page source, it's setup like so:

```
<a href="http://www.tephigram.weather.net/cgi-bin/razradar.cgi?zipcode=45822&amp;width=720&amp;height=486" target="main">
    <img border="0" dynsrc="http://www.tephigram.weather.net/cgi-bin/razradar.cgi?zipcode=45822&width=720&height=486" start="fileopen" src="http://www.tephigram.weather.net/cgi-bin/razradar.cgi?zipcode=45822&width=720&height=486">
</a>
```

Which sources this site:

http://www.tephigram.weather.net/cgi-bin/razradar.cgi?zipcode=45822&width=720&height=486

Via `dynsrc`:

http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/images/_IMG_DYNSRC.html
http://www.citycat.ru/doc/HTML/IExplorer.30/mmedia.htm

Basically, they're setting a regular old `<img>`'s source to be an external video clip.

Ironically, it looks like they're stealing it.

Comment: Are there any weather websites that allow you to do this legally?

Comment: @candyA: You can always email them, and ask for permission. [Here](http://www.weather.net/contact/) is their contact page.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the National Weather Service radar:
http://radar.weather.gov/radar.php?rid=LOT&product=N0R&overlay=11101111&loop=yes

If you fire up something like Fiddler, you can see the requests for the individual images being used to make the "loop".  In the past, I have created something where these frames were cropped to a specific area, and then placed into an animated GIF.  This is trivial with ImageMagick, or GD, which are generally available in PHP.  You could also do this with JavaScript if you were crafty with DIV overflow.

As for licensing, I believe you can use it without a license, but you should check with a lawyer who knows for sure.  I am not one.

Comment: What did your HTML look like? Can you be more specific?

Would I be able to use this map somehow? - http://image.weather.com/web/flash/FMMain.swf?&lat=38.9&long=-76.99&viewPortWidth=800&viewPortHeight=600&initialWeatherLayerType=radar&initialZoomLevel=5&wxAnimateOnStart=true

Comment: @candyA, That map you posted is from Weather.com, and I'm sure it is very restricted in use.  The good thing is though, with the NWS radar, you can overlay it on any map you want, provided it is the correct projection.  My HTML... just some image tags.  No, I can't be more specific, I haven't had that page up in 5 years.  I've told you exactly what you need to do.  Give it a try and post back as you have questions.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "overlay it on any map"?

Comment: @candyA, You can drop the radar images on top of whatever you want.  If you don't like the map that the NWS uses underneath the radar image, you can use your own.  Just be sure to use the correct projection.  http://www.srh.noaa.gov/jetstream/doppler/radarfaq.htm#projection

Answer (score 2):

The animations created by the NWS use a flash program called FLAnis, you can find more here: http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/flanis/ It is VERY easy to use and configure.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not entirely sure of how to without "stealing" it. `<div><img src="http:///images.intellicast.com/WxImages/RadarLoop/day_None_anim.gif" height="496" width="768"></div>` will work, but is   stealing from WUNDERGROUND INTELLICAST.

Comment: I hardly know anything about licensing laws, so DONT ASK ME..

Comment: However, I am sure that using that radar could get you in trouble due to licensing.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers on this page are severely outdated, don't use them anyway because we now use https instead of http here in 2023. Your website will be considered "Unsafe" if you include any frames/objects that are pointing to http:// by many modern browsers.

**The HTTP (old) way:**

If you still need http, and don't care about the unsafe thing, you can use [this site](http://zoomradar.com/free-content/radar-widget-2/) which is free/legal to use, it even has a wizard to make a custom embed for you. Here is an example embed for Latrobe, PA:

```
<iframe src="http://www.zoomforecast.com/zoomradar_weather_map/weather_image_user.php?key=QqKbiO1WI2CAo9g" width="600" height="500" style="border:0" frameBorder="0" seamless="seamless" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

This was an auto-generated snippet, you need to regenerate your own at their website. It is free, they just ask for a reference name to your website, so if/when it goes down, they can ditch the token.

There are many "widgets" for weather, but radar has become quite coveted by media sites and so providers have taken to charging a fee for their legitimate use. Using JavaScript to programmatically grab the images is not usually legal, so you best get permission before doing so!

**The HTTPS (secure/up to date way):**

The HTTPS way is your best bet, they are secure. [This website](https://www.windy.com/-Embed-widget-on-page/widgets) does a more up to date image embed like the last:

```
<iframe width="650" height="450" src="https://embed.windy.com/embed2.html?lat=40.292&lon=-79.405&detailLat=40.292&detailLon=-79.405&width=650&height=450&zoom=5&level=surface&overlay=wind&product=ecmwf&menu=&message=&marker=&calendar=now&pressure=&type=map&location=coordinates&detail=&metricWind=default&metricTemp=default&radarRange=-1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The big difference is that it is secure. Hope that helps anyone who ends up here (Wrote this because I hate dead ends and outdated info)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the HTML5 version of FLAnis https://www.ssec.wisc.edu/hanis/index.html
By following the link provided by jmcboots, I found this has been updated.

"...HTML5 AnimationS webapp (HAniS for short). This is a re-casting of the FLAniS Flash applet (which, of course was a re-casting of the original Java applet, AniS...which itself was a spinoff of the VISITview teletraining package), done in HTML5.

What does HAniS do? Like it predecessors, it is a tool you can employ on your web pages that provides the ability to animate a sequence of individual images. It also lets you use overlays and provides many options for creating "hotspots", probing data, and the like. This version is coded entirely in JavaScript and uses the HTML5 standards so is usable on multiple platforms with modern browsers.

The HAniS Model is the same as it predecessors: once the program starts, it reads configuration information that persists throughout the run/session (like the controls and layout). If your content (image filenames, for example) is changing with time, and you want the user to be able to "refresh" the content, then you put the dynamic information into a file_of_filenames which is re-read when a "refresh" is done, and usually contains the updated image filenames (and perhaps other, dynamic content). There are a few different ways of specifying the configuration information, but the file_of_filenames is a text file that must reside on the server with your image files."

Free Satellite Imagery Data Sources https://gisgeography.com/free-satellite-imagery-data-list/

or from your radar software (ie. Gibson Ridge) with ftp.